# Bound for the integral

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Is there any way to bound the following integral

$$\int_{-(\epsilon+1)/\sigma}^{(\epsilon-1)/\sigma} \mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$$

Comment: $\le\sqrt{ \frac\pi2}$ I guess

Comment: that means it is does not depend on $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$. Can you please give me the hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-(\epsilon+1)/\sigma}^{(\epsilon-1)/\sigma} \mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt\leqslant\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot(2\Phi(\epsilon/\sigma)-1)=\sqrt{2\pi}\,\mathrm{erf}(\epsilon/(\sigma\sqrt2))$$